# How to change bitnami redmine default URL

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, redmine, bitnami

Hi I have installed bitnami redmine to use agile.when ever I am writing localhost/ or 127.0.01/ it is accessing bitnami home page to link for redmine.

I want to change it so that it can be used with proper port number , for example i am thinking to give port 1234, so that localhost:1234 will be my address for it.

I have seen and tried {HOME}/apps/redmineplusagileconf/httpd-prefix , to change the access for redmine , but still not able to change the access with custome port.

Any suggestion would help me.

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP Port**

Under the default configuration, Apache will wait for requests on port 80. Change that by editing the `httpd.conf` file and modifying the value specified in the *Port directive*. For example:

```
Listen 1234

ServerName localhost:1234
```

Also change the port in `installdir/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` in the *VirtualHost directive*:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:1234>
```

**HTTPS Port**

Apache waits for HTTPS requests on port 443. Change that by editing the `installdir/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` file and modifying the value specified in the *Port directive*. For example:

```
Listen 8443

<VirtualHost _default_:8443>
```

In both cases, restart the Apache server for the change to take effect:

```
sudo installdir/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

> NOTE: On Linux and OS X platforms, install the stack as the root user
>   to use a port number under 1024.

Comment: thanks but localhost:1234/phpmyadmin is giving error,saying page not found

Comment: I only modify these files
`INSTALL_DIR/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`
`INSTALL_DIR/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`
with the values that I said you above and it works fine, including PHPMyAdmin. Now, I can access to Redmine and PHPMyAdmin using the port 1234.


You can try to modify the specific configuration, but it shouldn't be necessary. You can find it in
`INSTALL_DIR/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf`


Remember to restart Apache using `INSTALL_DIR/ctlscript.sh restart apache`